# having trouble with SQL Server Computed Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am working on a web application with a Javascript Backend developer.  We thought it would be useful to add a computed column to one of our tables to effectively act as a Unique ID per "event".

I have tried applying HASHBYTES to a concatenation of a timestamp and a User ID field, which works well in a Select statement.  However, when altering my Table with a Persisted (computed) column I receive the error:

> computed column {name} in table 'myTable' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

I am not entirely clear what this error is telling me.  Is it related to using a datetimeoffset field in my calculation?  Or am I trying to use `hashbytes` in an incorrect manner?  Is there a better way to compute and store a UUID?

Comment: Are you trying to store the computed column? You cannot do that, the database will compute the value for you.

Comment: I suspect this might help you:  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/transact-sql-hashbytes-deterministic-piotr-lipski/.

Comment: Please share a repro of the  issue along with DML of the table

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thank you for the link to LinkedIn!  That is exactly what I was struggling with!

Answer (score 1):

Are you relying on implicit conversions to generate the computed column? Try to get CONVERT function involved. Hashing a timestamp column is not deterministic and the CONVERT function can help make it deterministic if used as shown below.

> Select hashbytes('MD5',
>   convert(varchar(200),(CONVERT(varchar(10),datestamp,126)+'
>   '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),datestamp,114)),2)) from Events Where DateStamp
>   ='2016-06-30 12:19:35.257961'